# In a Django model class list view, how can I allow the user to select the ordering of the objects?

Tags: python, django-views, django-queryset

For a simple example, I have a Post Model and an associated Comments model in a blog.
In the Posts view I would like to have a dropdown with two options:
"Latest Posts", "Most Commented"

I am familiar with the ordering function, which works well for ordering by the latest posts, but I have not been able to find how to:

1. Order the posts by the number of comments
2. Allow the user to choose which order they want to see by submitting it in a dropdown form at the top.

An example of code doing an equivalent action in another repo would be enough to get me going, but unfortunately I was not able to find so.

Comment: Can you share the `Post` and `Comment` model?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `ForeignKey` from `Comment` to `Post`, You can sort by the `Count` of `Comment`s, so if the model looks like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # …

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …
```

Then the queryset can look like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.order_by(Count('comment').desc())
```

Comment: @Torres: well in order to select it interactively, you probably should use some JavaScript :)